# Is it possible to use a list defined in a given block in a where block in spock?

Tags: groovy, spock

For example:

```
given: "a list and a variable"
def checkThese = someStaticFunctionThatReturnsAList()
a = 5

expect: "a is greater than b"
a > b

where: "B is a list defined in given"
b << checkThese
//b << [1,2,3,4,5] will work, the above will not
```

This will fail and say there is no such property checkThese.  How can I accomplish this?

Comment: You could make `checkThese` a field in the class?

Comment: @tim_yates what do you mean by make it a field in the class?

Comment: @tim_yates I understand.  Isn't that bad practice?  Seems there should be an easier way to do this

Comment: There is; put it in the `where` block ;-)

Comment: @tim_yates let me make this a little more complicated and see what you think

Comment: Do you really need the intermediate variable `checkThese` here? Why not inline it? `b << someStaticFunctionThatReturnsAList()`

Comment: @Steinar you should post your comment as a full answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It does not work, because the `where:` block although written last in the spec method is actually executed first, since it is used for "data driven testing". It actually facilitates calling your method several times (for each data iteration that you set up there).

So in your case:

```
given: "a list and a variable"
def checkThese = someStaticFunctionThatReturnsAList() // this line will actually get executed every time your spec method runs
a = 5

expect: "a is greater than b"
a > b

where: "B is a list defined in given"
b << checkThese // will not work (because the given block is not executed yet and the variable is not created yet and not accessible
b << [1,2,3,4,5] // works because you're setting up the data explicitly
b << someStaticFunctionThatReturnsAList() // will also work
```

Comment: yeah I did some experimenting and actually came to this conclusion today.  Thanks!